# How to disable secure_file_priv in MySQL 8.0 in windows 10 machine?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

I tried to load csv file into table using

```
load  data infile 'C:\\a.csv' into table errorClick columns terminated by ',' lines terminated by ',\r\n' ignore 1 lines;
```

I am using sql version 8.0 It gave error:

```
Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement    0.000 sec
```

I ran this statement:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

The result is

```
secure_file_priv    C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\
```

Then i tried

```
 Set secure_file_priv="";
```

It gave result

```
Error Code: 1238. Variable 'secure_file_priv' is a read only variable   0.047 sec
```

Then I tried to find `my.ini` in my windows 10 machine at location

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\
```

I did not find any `my.ini` file; Please help me resolve this error;

Comment: Check MySQL service command line for pathname to actual .ini-file. Ensure that you have access rights enough for to browse its folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can only change it in my.inio file and then restart he server

You find my.ini in a hidden folder

> C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0

There you find under the section

> [mysqld]

```
secure-file-priv = ""
```

After the edit, you need to **restart the server**, so that the changes will take effect.

Comment: i cant find it i created and restared the service but it isnt affect

Comment: that depends on the installation, the default folders are described here. but when you start the service there you find also the location of the ini file if it differs. xampp bring their own folder structure

Comment: I figure out for windows 10 machines the folder location is  in my case C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7, the mysql is standalone not from a set of tools

Comment: you should install mysql 8, 5.7 is still suppor4ted but the newe version has many good features

Comment: yes, I agree with you but the companies has legacy infrastructure and databases

Comment: and so as to RESTART A SERVER: First, open the Run window by using the Windows+R keyboard.
Second, type services.msc and press Enter; Third, select the MySQL service and click the restart button.